# Declaration or statement expected with react bootstrap

Tags: typescript, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to use `react-bootstrap`with Typescript, but I got this error.

```
/home/vagnerwentz/Documents/www/wecanclub/node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/index.d.ts
TypeScript error in /home/vagnerwentz/Documents/www/wecanclub/node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/index.d.ts(2,1):
Declaration or statement expected.  TS1128

    1 | export { default as Accordion } from './Accordion';
  > 2 | export type { AccordionProps } from './Accordion';
      | ^
    3 | export { default as AccordionContext } from './AccordionContext';
    4 | export { default as AccordionCollapse } from './AccordionCollapse';
    5 | export type { AccordionCollapseProps } from './AccordionCollapse';
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have actually just run in to this issue as well.
It seems that you need to upgrade to TS 3.8 or downgrade react-bootstrap to 1.0.1.
Check this closed issue:
https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/5281

Comment: It's important to say that what needs to be changed is typescript's version in `package.json` (and not the global version), and to apply that change one must run `npm install` in the project directory.

Answer (score 7):

I tried this code and it was fixed

**npm i typescript@3.8**